# Angular 5 - x is not a function

Tags: angular

I have a data class like this:

```js
export class Question {
  public id: string;
  public createDate: Date;
  public translations: Translation[];
  public username: string;

  public getOriginalLanguage(): Translation{
    return this.translations.find(value => value.type == 'ORIGINAL');
  }
}
```

Now in my component receives this question object via `@Input()`. In `ngOnInit()` I want to call the `getOriginalLanguage()` on my question object. This always results in:

> TypeError: this.question.getOriginalLanguage is not a function

Comment: How is the `Question` object instantiated?

Comment: from a HTTP call http.get<Array<Question>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're simply getting this from an HTTP call, the function will not exist, as it is not in the JSON data that you're parsing.

Although this allows TypeScript to type the data as a `Question`, it doesn't automatically make it a fully fledged `Question` object with the function. You will need to do that yourself.

Change the `Question` so that we can populate the fields when instantiating it:

```js
export class Question {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public createDate: Date,
    public translations: Translation[],
    public username: string,
  ) {}

  public getOriginalLanguage(): Translation{
    return this.translations.find(value => value.type == 'ORIGINAL');
  }
}
```

And in your service:

```js
http.get("")
    .map((res) => res.map((q) => q = new Question(q.id, q.createdDate, q.translations, q.username)));
```

This will call map on your array, and convert each item into a `Question` object, *with* the function, by passing the values into the new constructor.

Answer (score -2):

this is because ngOnInit fires earlier than response is received (in your case);
try call getOriginalLang() inside of .subscribe() method;

Comment: The received object is passed to this component correctly. console.log in ngOnInit shows all the fields of the object